# Parent window open child window open but how to parent window is locked for tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code. parent window open child window open but how to  parent window is locked for tkinter in python.

````
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Registration form')
root.geometry("200x200") 
def openaddimage():
    addimage = Toplevel(root)
    addimage.title("Add image/screenshot below")
    addimage.geometry("400x200")


btn2 = Button(root, text='Add Image', width=10, bg='darkblue',
              fg='white', command=openaddimage).place(x=170, y=300)

root.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Do you want to disable the parent window until the child window is closed? If do use `addimage.grab_set()`

Comment: JacksonPro thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('Registration form')
root.geometry("200x200") 
def openaddimage():
    addimage = Toplevel(root)
    addimage.title("Add image/screenshot below")
    addimage.geometry("400x200")
    addimage.grab_set()

btn2 = Button(root, text='Add Image', width=10, bg='darkblue',
              fg='white', command=openaddimage).place(x=170, y=300)

root.mainloop()
```